# Unable to connect to remote shared path through xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql, sql-server, xp-cmdshell, net-use

I am trying to copy a file from a remote path to my local machine using xp_cmdshell in SQL management studio.

The following are the steps i use:

**1. Establish a connection**

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'net use L: \\remoteServer\folder /user:domain\username ImPWD'
```

**2. Re-connect**

When i execute `exec xp_cmdshell 'net use'`, the status of L is unavailable.
So I ran `exec xp_cmdshell 'net use L:'`
This doesn't help anyway. It still is unavailable!

**3. Copy file**

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'COPY L:\Fol1\SubFol2\File.xlsx C:\work\file.xlsx'
```

This is the error i get:

> The system cannot find the file specified.

I have tried the following but nothing seems to work yet:

- Found the user credentials that is used by xp_cmdshell and tried connecting to the shared path manually through windows UI and it seems to work. Therefore i concluded that there are no permission issues.`EXEC xp_cmdshell 'whoami.exe'`
- Ran the queries as a normal user and an administrator. Both resulted in the same output.

Here are my questions:

1. Am I missing some step?
2. Why is the connection getting unavailable after the first connect?
3. How to delete connection? i.e  When i run `exec xp_cmdshell 'net use * /delete'` it asks

> Do you want to continue this operation? (Y/N) [N]:
>   I am not sure how to say 'Y' using management studio query.

Thanks for your help in advance! :)

Comment: For the 3rd question: `exec xp_cmdshell 'net use * /delete /y' ` It will select Yes silently

Comment: @lad2025 thanks! that works perfectly! When i delete and add the connection again, the connection status become 'OK' which was previously 'unavailable'. Now the only issue remaining is, it is still not copying. Getting the same error.

Comment: Guess i have found the answer after two days of crazy debugging! LOL! It was just the folder name issue. Folder names with spaces!!! It works like a charm if i wrap the path in double quotes!

Comment: Great to hear that it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to delete connection?

To delete connection use:

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'net use * /delete /y'
```

(yes) will be silently passed

As for other questions: you mentioned in comment that your folders in path have spaces so you could:

- rename folders
- wrap with `""`